SSL handshake failed while connecting to strimzi's Kafka using SASL_SSL (TLS + SCRAM-SHA-512)
I have a strimzi Kafka cluster deployed on Azure Kubernetes.
Following this guide I have configured listeners and auth as follows.
    authorization:
      type: simple
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
      - name: external
        port: 9093
        type: ingress
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        configuration:
          class: nginx
          bootstrap:
            host: bootstrap-${domain}
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            host: broker-0-${domain}
          - broker: 1
            host: broker-1-${domain}
          - broker: 2
            host: broker-2-${domain}

The SCRAM authentication works fine for the 9092 internal non tls listener. When I try to connect outside of the cluster though the client throws
ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (kafka-kafka-external-bootstrap/10.0.67.251:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

While server side all I get is:
[SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.224.0.30 (channelId=10.224.0.45:9093-10.224.0.30:50796-19968) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9093)-SASL_SSL-8]

As strimzi configures the ingress for the Kubernetes nginx ingress project, while I am using the nginx one, I thought I must had set up the TLS passthrough wrong, so I tried accessing the external service directly from a kafka-client pod inside the cluster. Same error. Changed the listener type to loadbalancer. Same error.
Client config
As strimzi deploys these secrets
kafka-clients-ca                    Opaque   1      21h
kafka-clients-ca-cert               Opaque   3      21h
kafka-cluster-ca                    Opaque   1      21h
kafka-cluster-ca-cert               Opaque   3      21h
kafka-cluster-operator-certs        Opaque   4      21h
kafka-entity-topic-operator-certs   Opaque   4      21h

I've configured the client.properties file
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="master" password="pwd";
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/creds/cluster.p12
ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
ssl.truststore.password=pwd

Where the truststore cluster.p12 is taken from the secret kafka-cluster-ca-cert -> ca.p12, and the password from kafka-cluster-ca-cert -> ca.password.
The master user auth works with SASL_PLAINTEXT over the 9092 port.
So I launched
kafka-console-producer.sh \ \
            --producer.config /tmp/creds/client.properties \
            --broker-list kafka-kafka-external-bootstrap:9093 \
            --topic test

What am I missing?

Without a full log, it is not clear what the SSL issue is. But when connecting to the internal service such as kafka-kafka-external-bootstrap:9093, you will likely fail hostname verification. If you use external listener, you should connect from the outside using the external address. E.g. whatever the bootstrap-${domain} is.

@Jakub that's the problem, that's the whole log of the error. strimzi allows the service to be set to laodbalancer too, which only has an IP. This should eliminate the hostname verification problem, but I get the same error.

I think the Kafka client will always do hostname verification. You need to use the right address. As for the logs, you can configure the logging.
